# GoogleMaps API Geocoding Callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

A simple one that I cannot seem to get to work properly.

I have the following:

```
    function geocode(address, callback) {
    if (typeof (geocoder) == 'undefined') geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback({ Latitude: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), Longitude: results[0].geometry.location.lng() });
        }
        else {
            callback(0);
            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

That gets called by:

```
            var latitude = '';
            var longitude = '';
            geocode(self.address(), function (result) {
                if (result === 0) {
                    //Error with geocoding
                }
                else {
                    latitude = result.Latitude;
                    longitude = result.Longitude;
                }
            });
//Do some stuff with latitude and longitude
```

Now, the results do return, however they do so asynchronously which is what I thought the callback would overcome e.g. `latitude` and `longitude` value are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think this i the correct way

```
var latitude = '';
var longitude = '';
geocode(self.address(), function (result) {
    if (result === 0) {
        //Error with geocoding
    }
    else {
        .... 
        manage  your latitude, longitude

        ....
    }
});


 function geocode(address) {
    if (typeof (geocoder) == 'undefined') geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude =results[0].geometry.location.lng() });
        }
        else {

            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, unfortunately your suggestion does not work, I'm actually not sure how it could work as you are not directly processing this as a callback therefor it would be asynchronous. Maybe I wasn't clear, the latitude and longitude values 'work' it's just that the values do not populate 'in time' (because the call to gecode is asynchronous).